# I'm inserting placemarks in leaflet map with jQuery. But when I try to insert the placemarks by clicking a link it gives me error

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

The error I get is "Uncaught Error: Map container is already initialized."
 The function placethemarks() loads data by using another function pullJson() that divides the data I want to visualize on the map by clicking a corresponding link. How can I solve this error ?

```
$(window).load(function(){                 
         var element = $('#mapPage');         
         element.height(element.height() - 42);             
         var map = L.map('map').setView([44.493889, 11.342778], 13);          
         L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',               
         attributionControl = false).addTo(map);         

    });


function placethemarks(){
 var jsondata = pullJsonData();
         var marker_art = new Array();
         var marker_museum = new Array();   

        for(var a in jsondata){
            var tipocat = jsondata[a].type; 

            if(tipocat=='artwork') {
                storeCoordinate(jsondata[a].geometry.coordinates[0], jsondata[a].geometry.coordinates[1], marker_art);
            }
            else if(tipocat == 'arts_centre'||tipocat == 'museum' ) {
                storeCoordinate(jsondata[a].geometry.coordinates[0], jsondata[a].geometry.coordinates[1], marker_museum);
            }
         }

        var marker_array = []; 
         for (var i = 0; i < marker_art.length; i++) {
          var x = marker_art[i].x;
          var y = marker_art[i].y;
          var arr = [y,x];
          marker_array.push(arr);

         }

         for(var i = 0; i < marker_array.length-1; i++){
                   new L.marker(marker_array[i]).addTo(map);
         }

      }
```

Art

Museums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved finally the problem by simply adding to the code the Leaflet map I had to add. Now when i click the button I see the placemarks added to the map . Hese is the code :

```
  <div id = "butt">
        <button type="button" onClick = placeTheMarks()>Place The Marks!</button>
        </div>

     <script>
         function placeTheMarks(){       

           // I take the data from another page 
           var json = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('response'));

             var marker_art = new Array();
             var marker_museum = new Array();   
             for(var a in json){
                var tipocat = json[a].type; 

                if(tipocat=='artwork') {
                    storeCoordinate(json[a].geometry.coordinates[0], json[a].geometry.coordinates[1], marker_art);
                }
                else if(tipocat == 'arts_centre' || tipocat == 'museum' ) {
                    storeCoordinate(json[a].geometry.coordinates[0], json[a].geometry.coordinates[1], marker_museum);
                }
             }
            var marker_array = []; 
             for (var i = 0; i < marker_art.length; i++) {
              var x = marker_art[i].x;
              var y = marker_art[i].y;
              var arr = [y,x];
              marker_array.push(arr);

             }

             for(var i = 0; i < marker_array.length-1; i++){
                       new L.marker(marker_array[i]).addTo(map);
             }
         }

            var map = L.map('map').setView([44.7215826, 10.624086], 12);

             L.tileLayer("http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
                attribution: 'Map data&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
               }).addTo(map);

            </script>
```